# Rewrite htacces can't find files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I made an ajax website that call php pages from /pages folder inside my `index.php`, so i made a rewrite in `htaccess` for return all my pages in my index so the ajax working well but when clicking refresh the page button or on first load, the function can't find files, return `404.php` page all the time:

This is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*).php$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

And this is my php function calling my pages:

```
<div id="ajax-container">
<?php
 $d = "pages/";
 if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = strtolower($_GET['p']);
    if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/", $p) && file_exists($d . $p . ".php")) {
        include $d . $p . ".php";
    } else {
        include $d . "404.php";
    }
 } else {
    include $d . "home.php";
 }
?>
</div>
```

I think the problem come from my rewrite because it's rewrite all pages php so I think it's also rewriting my `index.php` and so the function can't find the `['p']` but I'm not sure and I don't know if it's this how can I rewrite only files from my `/pages` folder

Comment: You probably want the server filepath in your `file_exists()` function, try defining `$d = realpath( __DIR__ . '/pages/' );` - you might want to add some sanity checks like `is_dir()` as well.

Comment: the problem stay, actually i don't understand why the function can't find my  pages because it find the folder, it returns the 404.php page so why it can't find the other pages

Comment: Oh yeah - that's exactly what's happening, you need the standard *not file* *not directory* conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index.php` is getting picked up by your Rewrite on the second pass and being sent to `index.php?p=index` which doesn't have a corresponding page in your *pages* directory and so fetches `404.php`.

The *normal* way to avoid this is to add conditions for *not file* and *not directory* into your .htaccess (thus preventing URLs to files or directories that actually exist from being rewritten).

You can do that by simply changing your .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.php$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

See Apache's [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) manual.

Comment: Yes thank you it's working but now i have an other problem it's working well on first load ( the home.php is return) but when i click on one of my ajax link page ( for example about.php ) and i refresh the page, it's return only the about.php, but don't return it inside my index.php

Comment: Do you have 2 `about.php` pages? One in the root and one in `/pages` ?

Comment: oups :x... yes ... i forget it when i tried to find a solution, i will whip myself sorry :) thank you for your help ;)

Comment: No worries :) One way you could avoid that problem is to use the extension `.phtml` for your files in the `/pages` directory; they are your *Views* and are a mix of HTML and PHP so using .phtml makes sense... you're actually slowly working towards an MVC design pattern ;)